# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apscheduler.schedulers'; 'apscheduler' is not a package

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apscheduler.schedulers'; 'apscheduler' is not a package

Errors like this occur.

I have already installed the apscheduler library.

Version used: python3.11.0

Framework in use: Django

**apscheduler.py**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz
import requests
import json
from .models import Todo

def notify_todo():
    #現在の時刻を取得
    now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))
    #締切が24時間以内のTODOリストを取得
    todos = Todo.objects.filter(deadline__range=(now, now + timedelta(days=1)))

    for todo in todos:
        #LINE NotifyのAPIトークンを取得
        api_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

        #通知メッセージの作成
        message =  f"【{todo.title}】\n締切時間：{todo.deadline.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')}\n詳細：{todo.description}"

        #LINE Notifyに通知を送信
        headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_token}'}
        payload = {'message': message}
        requests.post('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', headers=headers, data=payload)


#BackgroundSchedulerの設定
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone='Asia/Tokyo')
scheduler.add_job(notify_todo, 'interval', minutes=10)#10分ごとに実行
scheduler.start()
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("タスク名", max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField("詳細", blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateField("締切")
    ttime = models.TimeField("")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class TodoConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'todo'

def ready(self):
    from .apscheduler import start
    start()
```

[image: Directory Structures]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a module `apscheduler` somewhere that gets imported instead of the actual package. Do you have an `apscheduler.py` in your project directory? If so, delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have apscheduler.py in my applications folder.

Is that why the error occurs?

I have attached a picture of the directory structure.

Comment: Yes, that `apscheduler.py` is loaded instead, which is why you're seeing that error.

Comment: You should always arrange your own modules into packages, or otherwise they might conflict with something else. If you expected `import apscheduler` to import the APScheduler library, how did you expect to import your own `apscheduler.py` then?